# How to determine the degree of uniform distribution of a list?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I would like to determine how much the members of a set are distributed in an uniform way. With 'uniform' I mean, how much all points have the same distance to each other.

**Example:**

I define a list of numbers, so that the distance to the next neighbor is always the same:

```
x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

If I take the inverse of that set:

```
x2 = sorted(1/x1)
```

I get something like

```
['0.100', '0.111', '0.125', '0.143', '0.167', '0.200', '0.250', '0.333', '0.500', '1.000']
```

`x1` is very equidistant, `x2` is less equidistant than `x1`.

**Question:**

Is there any commonly accepted way of calculating the amount of 'equidistanceness' for such a situation?

Comment: Maybe numpy.diff() and take the mean?

Comment: There is no commonly accepted way that I'm aware of, but I think `np.std(np.diff(x1))` might be a decent measure of what you're describing.

Comment: @wim: thanks, that looks already very nice. Taking also the min and max values of the list into account, would lead accordingly to: `np.diff(x).std() / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))` (the min and max make sense to be independent from any scaling effects)